# Windows 10 Set default wallpaper for anyone who logs in?

Tags: windows, powershell, wallpaper

Is there a way to set the default wallpaper for a new user logging into windows 10? I was supplied with the script below but only works for the current user. Is this possible to set it for any user that logs in?

```
Function Set-WallPaper($Value)
 {
    Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -name wallpaper -value $value
    rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
 }
```

Comment: Use it as a logon script for all users on the machine

Comment: Thanks but I would like to just set it once I don't want to force it to be changed everytime they login because I want the user the ability to set their own as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason that registry entry doesn't work with new profiles in Windows 10.  Some other setup process clobbers it.  I've seen scripts where the default .jpg is made writeable and then replaced.  http://ccmexec.com/2015/08/replacing-default-wallpaper-in-windows-10-using-scriptmdtsccm/

Answer (score 1):

You can access all loaded user registry hives through the `HKEY_USERS` hive.

It's not automatically mounted like `HKCU:` or `HKLM:`, but you can access it with a provider-qualified path, like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Registry::HKEY_USERS
```

I'd also suggest that you declare your parameters properly as well:

```
function Set-WallPaper
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$WallPaperFile,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$All
    )

    if($All){
        foreach($UserHive in Get-ChildItem Registry::HKEY_USERS){
            $DesktopKeyPath = (Join-Path $UserHive.PSPath "Control Panel\Desktop")
            if(Test-Path $DesktopKeyPath){
                Set-ItemProperty -Path $DesktopKeyPath -Name Wallpaper -Value $WallPaperFile.FullName
            }
        }
    } else {
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -Name wallpaper -Value $WallPaperFile.FullName
    }

    rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
}
```

Comment: Thank you script seems to work fine without errors but I logged on as a different user and the wallpaper is not changed even after a reboot

Comment: Did you run it with the -All switch?

Comment: Like this?    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -Name wallpaper -Value $WallPaperFile.FullName -all

Comment: No, `Set-WallPaper -All`

Comment: I tried that Set-WallPaper -All -WallPaperFile "Pathtowallpaper" and still no luck. It is windows 10 not sure that matters